# Is there a wordpress plugin that makes an iframe's height the same as its content?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

Background:
I have a couple of different websites on different domains. All of these websites have a part which is identical. Therefore I've made this part into its own page, and want to incorporate it into the websites with an iframe. That way, only one page needs to be updated to change the identical part on all the websites.

Problem:
At this time, I'm using the plugin *Advanced iFrame* to add the iframe to the website:

`[advanced_iframe src="addressToPage" width="100%"]`

but I can't get its height to be the same as the height of the page it's displaying. Is there a way to do this with *Advanced iFrame* or is there another wordpress plugin that allows me to do this? Note that I want the iframe to be the height of the page it's containing, not the height page the iframe is being diplayed on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iframes can only do this if the iframe's src is on the same domain or if there's an explicit communications channel between two domains via something like window.postMessage. You can't do it with a random website that's outside your control.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok, thank you!